# ¿Por qué un grupo devuelve únicamente la última captura?

Tags: python, regex

¿Por que me devuelve `('b', 'c')` y no `('a', 'b', 'c')`?

```
r = re.findall(r'(var (((a|b),)*)(c))' , 'var a,b,c') 
for g in r:
    print g
```

Comment: Bievenido para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida te invito a lee [ask] según los consejos que leas ahí editala y evita que sea cerrada

Comment: @Raul gracias por intentar que se mejore la calidad... Sin embargo, en este caso, al menos yo, no noté que le faltara nada

Answer (score 2):

Un grupo que es repetido y coincide más de una vez sobrescribe el valor capturado con su última ocurrencia.

Así funcionan las expresiones regulares. El regex

```
(ejemplo)+
```

siempre va a capturar y devolver la última ocurrencia en el texto `ejemploejemploejemplo`.

---

Para obtener más de un valor, se debe coincidir más de una vez, en vez de repetir los grupos. Hay 3 estrategias posibles:

1. Usar un grupo exterior que capture a todo el texto repetido. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   r"var ((?:[ab],)*)(c)"
   ```

   que te captura dos grupos: `a,b,` y `c`. Luego, deberías separar lo que obtengas del primer grupo.
2. En vez de `re`, usar el [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) de Matthew Barnett, un módulo más avanzado que implementa el uso de [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) para coincidir con [el final de la coincidencia anterior](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). Ejemplo:

   ```
   >>> import regex

   >>> regex.findall(r"(?:var |\G(?!^),)([abc])", "var a,b,c")
   ['a', 'b', 'c']
   ```

   [Demo 1 (findall)](https://repl.it/@Mariano_SOes/RepeatGroup); [Demo 2 (finditer)](https://repl.it/@Mariano_SOes/GruposRepetidosFindIter)
3. La más fea, que sólo funcionaría en casos muy concretos, cuando el número de coincidencias tiene un máximo fijo, se declaran tantos grupos como ocurrencias pueda haber y se ponen como opcionales:

   ```
   r"var (?:(a),)?(?:(b),)?(c)"
   ```